# Get all children (users) from firebase but show button to one child (user)?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]I want to show a button to only one user among all users.
I tried `orderByKey()` but it didn't worked !

The user model has id member, i tried with `orderByChild("id")` but same result !

I tried even the below trick !

```
int times=0; //class varaible

 usersListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot ds, String ss) {
                OnlineUser ou = ds.getValue(OnlineUser.class);
                if (ou == null) return;
                if (times == 0 && myId.equals(ou.id)) {
                    times++;
                    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
//rest of the code
```

For Ex: If children (users) list contains 4 members, I want to show the button to only one person or for the first person who inserted data. I don't want to use timeStamp node in user's model.

Comment: make sure "myId" is static final it should not update?!

Comment: can you tell me if the button was shown in all users or no button was shown in any users?

Comment: by default button is invisible (View.GONE), i want to show the button for only one user or for the first user. But the problem is "The first user is not same for all users". It shows self details first , I mean his account comes first in on Child Added !

Comment: The code you shared doesn't show what reference or query you attached the listener, so it's impossible to say what it does. Most likely you will actually have to use a query to limit the data that is returned, as Sagar's answer points at.

Comment: Tq you for reply Mr. Frank, but i needed to load all children. while loading enable the button to first child. I attached listener to database reference.

Comment: by telling it didn't work, i want to also know, how the button is showing i.e. showing for all 4 or not showing at all

Comment: I updated my question with image ! Take a look.

Comment: i got your question alright. What i meant was how was the buttons showing currently (right now) on the code you implemented.

Comment: At the beginning button was hidden to all users and after running trails button was showing to all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially (in the xml) by setting the button visibility to "gone" and then implementing the code something like this:

```
int times=0; //class varaible

usersListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot ds, String ss) {
            OnlineUser ou = ds.getValue(OnlineUser.class);
            if (ou == null) return;
            if (times == 0 && myId.equals(ou.id)) {
                times++;
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
```

**will not work to show button to only first user**. Rather the button will be visible to all users since now the visibility property of the button is set to visible. Hence it will be visible to every child elements/users.

You are missing to again reset the visibility to gone. So I suggest following to your code:

```
int times=0; //class varaible

usersListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot ds, String ss) {
            OnlineUser ou = ds.getValue(OnlineUser.class);
            if (ou == null) return;
            if (times == 0 && myId.equals(ou.id)) {
                times++;
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
//rest of the code
```

Comment: Thanks for trying friend @Ujjwal, It is solved by checking first 2 children (users) whose id was small (only to enable button to one user) and setting button visible to that person. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

What you might be looking is a `Firebase Query` which gives you the capability to find a child according to your need. Take a look at the docs here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query

Take a look at the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` method.